# How to determine if this map is open or closed?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Given two supspaces $X:= [0,1]\cup[2,3]$ and $Y:=[0,2]$ of $\mathbf{R}$, let $f \colon X \to Y$ be defined as follows: $$f(x):= \left\{ \begin{array} {ll} x & \mbox{if $0\leq x\leq 1;$} \\ x-1 & \mbox{if $2\leq x \leq 3.$} \end{array} \right.$$ Then while $f$ is surjective and continuous, how can we rigorously determine if it is an open or closed map as well?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

1. $[0,1]$ is open in $X$; is $f\big[[0,1]\big]$ open in $Y$?
2. Suppose that $K\subseteq X$ is closed. Then $K\cap[0,1]$ and $K\cap[2,3]$ are closed in $X$. Are $f\big[K\cap[0,1]\big]$ and $f\big[K\cap[2,3]\big]$ closed in $Y$? What can you say about the union of two closed sets?

Answer (score 1):

Hint for closedness: Note that $X$ is compact, so every closed subset of it is also compact. What do you know about the continuous images of compact sets? And what do you know about compact subsets of a Hausdorff space (such as $Y$)?